# NLP conversation data - Pre-processing steps

Tags: nlp, text-mining, preprocessing, text

I have text data, so data that has been transcribed from conversations from employees to customers. So each call has a recording that has been transcribed to text.

I am looking to do some analytics with the text data.

My main question, which I think is the most important, what would be the first pre-processing step to use with the text data in order to make it usable from an analytics perspective, possibly using supervised machine learning.

Do you use word to vector, sentence to vector, paragraph to vector etc?

Possible to provide links to examples etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my opinion it would be a mistake to do the preprocessing before designing the exact target task. The preprocessing depends on the goal, different choices of representation are suitable for different tasks.

Comment: @Erwan ! I hope your well! Thank you for your response! I know its a bit premature, but could you recommend some starting options in terms of pre-processing data. This is in terms of ease of use and availability of prebuilt code.

Comment: Well the first choice is whether to use traditional bag of words methods like TFIDF or word embeddings. Both are very common, the first one is easier and more interpretable, embeddings usually give more accurate results but require larger data. But even this choice should be made depending on the goal imho.

Comment: Thank you Erwan! Much appreciated I will look into both techniques.